# Mixing /MTd and /MDd options in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, heap-corruption

I have a unit test app for my C++ dll. The unit test is written using google test framework and needs /MTd (multi threaded debug) as Runtime library setting in Visual Studio (2013). The dll is compiled with /MDd (multi threaded debug dll). When I run the unit test app, I get the heap corruption error. I am suspecting it is because of dll and exe using different setting. If I try to compile my unit test app with /MDd I get multiple defined symbols linker error. Is this a problematic to compile with these settings? What is the correct way to solve it?

Comment: Investigate why you can't compile your test app with `/MDd`  With the different setting you basically have 2 active C/C++ runtime support libraries and therefore 2 heaps. If memory is allocated in one and passed to the other and deallocated you will get heap corruption.

Comment: I know it's years ago, but do you remember if you find a solution to this problem? I have run into the exact same problem.

Comment: @oscfri: It was actually asked in Feb this year :) No I havent been able to solve this till now.

Comment: "google test framework" itself should not requre /MT or /MTd itself. At least I use it with /MD and /MDd successfully. If you just have it precompiled into static library, go to Github, grab latest sources, then produce one huge "fused" source (they provide Python scipt for that) and include that into your VS project just as yet anoter source file.